# Assign php object to the jquery variable with laravel

Tags: jquery, laravel

I would like to assign json object to the jquery variable. But when i try it i get error:

```
htmlentities() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given (View: /var/www/html/resources/views/index.blade.php)
```

What's the easy way to do this?
Here is my code:

```
        var data = {};
        data = "{{$stationData}}";
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Laravel 5 and above it's:

```
data = {!! str_replace("'", "\'", json_encode($stationData)) !!};
```

in Laravel 4

```
data = {{{ str_replace("'", "\'", json_encode($stationData)) }}};
```

You need to escape this format twice. Otherwise can act strangly.

Answer (score 3):

You could do this by json encoding the PHP variable within your JavaScript. This will only work with inline JavaScript code, like so:

```
<?php
$foo = 'bar';
?>
<script>
    var foo = <?php echo json_encode($foo) ?>;
<script>
```

Another option to pass data from the backend to the front-end is by using AJAX. [This SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8567114/how-to-make-an-ajax-call-without-jquery) explains how this is done with and without jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

```
data = {{json_encode($stationData)}};
```

Answer (score 0):

$stationData beeing an Eloquent object, you could do something like this:

```
var foo = {{$stationData->toJson()}}
```

or any of the other answers.